# Is there a way to query MongoDB Rest API with a list or array of IDs

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using a MEAN stack and with Mongoose. Is there a way to query MongoDB with multiple ids to only return those specific IDs in one query e.g. /api/products/5001,5002,5003

Is this possible or would I need to query each product individually or add an additional attribute to the products and query by that.

Update: To clarify as suggested below I've managed to get it partially working using `{'_id': { $in: [5001,5002,5003]}` however I'm having problems figuring out how to pass the list from the api url to the find function.

Using Express.js for router
    router.get('/list/:ids', controller.showByIDs);

```
exports.showByIDs = function(req, res) { 
  Product.find({'_id': { $in: [req.params.ids]}}, function (err, product) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!product) { return res.send(404); }
    return res.json(product);
  }) 
};
```

Then trying /api/products/list/5001 works however /api/products/list/5001,5002 doesn't. I'm not sure if it's a syntax problem in the url or my router code that needs to change or the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator to query for multiple values at once:

```js
Products.find({_id: {$in: [5001, 5002, 5003]}}, function (err, products) { ... });
```

On the Express side, you need to use a format for the `ids` parameter that lets you split it into an array of id values, like you had in your first example:

```
/api/products/5001,5002,5003
```

Then in your route handler, you can call the `split` function on the `req.params.ids` string to turn it into an array of id values that you can use with `$in`:

```js
exports.showByIDs = function(req, res) { 
  var ids = req.params.ids.split(',');
  Product.find({'_id': { $in: ids}}, function (err, product) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!product) { return res.send(404); }
    return res.json(product);
  }) 
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that part. What I'm having problems with is how to pass that array via the rest api. I'm using `router.get('/list/:ids', controller.showByIDs);` (which I'm not certain will work in this case) and I can't figure out what the syntax needs to be in both the api e.g. api/products/list/5001,5002,5003 or api/products/list?ids=[5001,5002,5003] or whatever and what corresponding controller syntax needs to be in order to get the list of ids. I tried using `exports.showByIDs = function(req, res) { Product.find({'_id': { $in: req.params.ids}}, function (err, product) {...}) };`

Comment: Thanks I figured out a similar solution last night. I think I must have had a syntax error at first as I wasn't getting the param.ids passed through at all. I ended up using `var productids =JSON.parse("[" + req.params.ids + "]");` but I'm pretty sure your solution would work just as well.